# Android Speech Recognition stops listening immediately

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I developed a program with fully functioning speech recognition based off an example on the Android website.

I've made no changes to the code and it just suddenly stopped working. It starts to listen (you can hear the noise), then instantly it stops (you hear the ending noise).

Has anyone else had this problem or have any idea how I can resolve it? Here is the code, there are no errors being output when it runs, just the listener stops almost immediately as it starts listening.

```
/**
 * This method is called when the Speech Recognizer starts to listen for speech input
 */ 
@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i("SRL", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.i("SRL", "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

/**
 * This method is called after the speech input has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i("SRL", "onEndOfSpeech");
}

/**
 * This method is called if there has been an error during speech input
 * @param errorCode
 */
@Override
public void onError(int errorCode) {
    String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
    Log.d("SRL", "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    m_speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    m_speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
    m_speech.startListening(getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.i("SRL", "onEvent");
}

/**
 * This method is called if the speech recognizer thinks only partial speech was
 * input/recognized
 * @param arg0
 */
@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i("SRL", "onPartialResults");
}

/**
 * This method is called when the speech recognizer is ready for input
 * @param arg0
 */
@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.i("SRL", "onReadyForSpeech");
}

/**
 * This method is called when the speech recognizer has recieved input and recognized it.
 * It updates the recognized speech text view on the screen to show users what they have input.
 * @param results the text that has been input
 */
@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    recognizedSpeech = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recognizedSpeech);
    Log.i("SRL", "onResults");
    ArrayList<String> matches = results
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    String text = "";
    for (String result : matches)
        text += result + "\n";
    recognizedSpeech.setText(text);

    if (recognizedSpeech.getText().toString().contains("yes")) {
        PropertySquare square = (PropertySquare) (m_board.getSquare(
                players.get(m_currentTurn).getCurrentPosition()));

        square.setOwnedBy(players.get(m_currentTurn).getName());
        convertTextToSpeech("You now own" + square.getName());
        Log.d("buyProperty yes", square.getOwnedBy());

        if(manageFunds) {
            players.get(m_currentTurn).subtractMoney(square.getPrice());
            Log.d("buyProperty yes", players.get(m_currentTurn).getName() +
                String.valueOf(players.get(m_currentTurn).getMoney()));

            funds.setText(String.valueOf(players.get(m_currentTurn).getMoney()));
        }
    }
    nextTurnRoll();
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    Log.i("SRL", "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
}

/**
 * This method returns what error was caused if the speech recgonizer throws an error code
 * @param errorCode int representing the error thrown
 * @return log message including error details
 */
public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

UPDATE:

Looking through the application logs I have found that onRMSChanged is continuously running. Does this mean that the speech recognition is continuously running too, therefore causing my application to not pick up any speech?

Comment: "the listener stops" = the corresponding function returns? what about error codes/exceptions?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev by the listener stops there was no onResults method called or onEndOfSpeech or even onError, you can simply hear the start listening sound and immediately after the stop listening sound, although this is not replicated in the debug console. In the console you can see that the listener starts to listen, but it never stops as onRmsChanged is just constantly called thereafter, even though the stop listening sound has been given. 
Strangely I added an internet permission and interact with all users permission and it seems to be working fine as before. No idea how or what affected it.

Comment: Maybe changes in the security model. Any (automatic) updates installed?

Comment: Regardless, if you resolved the problem, you should post the resolution as an answer and accept it if nothing better is posted - so it may help future readers and the question is marked solved.

Comment: The resolution was nothing to do with the internet permission.

The solution was ensuring the wifi was connected. TTS seems to need an internet connection.

Comment: I wonder why... the software may very well turn out to be SaaS(S) actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the resolution was to ensure that the device was connected to the internet. I think that the TTS engine's need to connect to the correct internet host when changed and therefore would not listen if there was no internet connection.

Comment: If you have installed your local language packages in your phone, the Speech Recognizer will be fast and it can work offline.

Comment: @Francisco Durdin Garcia How to install local language package?

Comment: Note that Google seems to have retired its legacy speech-to-text (S2T) services [around May 2019](https://randocity.com/2012/04/03/google-android-how-to-fix-speech-to-text-couldnt-connect-error/), so this couldn't be the root cause of your issue. But it helps to know that Google is capable of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my instant NO_MATCH error by removing the offline preferred parameter that I had enabled on the intent.

```
//Intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline, true);
```

Comment: It has helped also in case of my problems, but I'm curious why...
Does it mean the bug is in the android.speech library?